# Anyone knows of a LGPL image converter command utility?

Tags: c#, image-processing

Unfortunately, I can't reduce the color depth of a Bitmap created in C# to 4-colors; therefore, I need a command utility that has this capability. I wasn't be able to solve this problem programmatically. I need something like IrfanView but it has to work with command prompt and must be LGPL so that I can use it in a commercial product.  Before I go insane can someone refer me a software that does that?

Thanks.

Comment: You only need LGPL if you want to link it. IMO GPL will be acceptable. Correct me if I am wrong however :)

Comment: Ok I'll check that leppie, but do you know any software that does that.

Comment: Please remove that note about LGPL - you just need anything that can be used in commercial product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/ seems to have a licensing even for commercial products.

Answer (score 2):

ImageMagick will do the trick. Note that it's under Apache 2.0 license, but you can use it in commercial products as it is not copyleft.

Comment: I am checking ImageMagick now but the portable version is 40 MB. Do you know of any smaller application ?

Comment: Maybe you should build it from sources with strictly limited configuration?

Answer (score 1):

If "can be used in a commercial product" is the important bit and not "LGPL", http://www.imagemagick.org/ is Apache 2 licence.